# How to get data from the firestore, render it in the server using @nguniversal/express-engine / @angular/ssr?

Tags: angular

Note:

1. tested on Angular 13 and 17. both does not work.

my goal is to get data from the firestore, render it in the server using `@nguniversal/express-engine` or `@angular/ssr`.

The problem is:

1. It is not rendered in the server, instead, it is rendered in the client.

Standard API call i.e. to a GoLang backend, gets rendered in the server. Only Firestore that does not render in the server. I am so confused.

What I've tried:

1. call the AngularFirestore in the Angular [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

   using Resolve works. But felt that this is not right. For example:

   1. Why must put it in `Route`?
   2. Why can't put it in the `Component`?.
2. call the AngularFirestore in the Angular Component, and change the data type to `Observable<any>`
3. call the AngularFirestore in the Angular Component, and subscribe to the observable instead of changing the data type to `Observable<any>`.

=== call the AngularFirestore in the Angular [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve). ===

So, if we call the firestore in the `Component`, and change the data type to `Observable<any>`, it will not be rendered in the server, instead it will rendered in the client.

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ExperiencesComponent } from './experiences/experiences.component';
import { UsersResolver } from './resolver';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ExperiencesComponent,
    resolve: { users: UsersResolver }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

users.resolver.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersResolver implements Resolve<any[]> {
  constructor(private _angularFirestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  resolve(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this._angularFirestore.collection('experiences', ref => ref.limit(20)).get().pipe(
      map(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          return doc.data();
        });
      }
      ),
      catchError(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
        return of([]);
      }));
  }
}
```

experiences.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-experiences',
  templateUrl: './experiences.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./experiences.component.scss']
})
export class ExperiencesComponent implements OnInit {
  allExperiences: any[] = [];
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.allExperiences = (this.route.snapshot.data as any).users;
  }

}
```

experiences.component.html

```
Hello
<div *ngFor="let item of allExperiences">{{ item?.experienceTitle }}</div>
```

=== call the AngularFirestore in the Angular Component, and change the data type to `Observable<any>` ===

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ExperiencesComponent,
    // resolve: { users: UsersResolver }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

experiences.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-experiences',
  templateUrl: './experiences.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./experiences.component.scss']
})
export class ExperiencesComponent implements OnInit {
  allExperiences: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
    ) {
      this.allExperiences = this._angularFirestore.collection('experiences', ref => ref.limit(20)).get().pipe(
        map(snapshot => {
          return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
            return doc.data();
          });
        }
        ),
        catchError(error => {
          console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
          return of([]);
        }));
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.allExperiences = (this.route.snapshot.data as any).users;
  }

}
```

experiences.component.html

```
Hello
<div *ngFor="let item of allExperiences | async">{{ item?.experienceTitle }}</div>
```

3. call the AngularFirestore in the Angular Component, and subscribe to the observable instead of changing the data type to `Observable<any>`.

experiences.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-experiences',
  templateUrl: './experiences.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./experiences.component.scss']
})
export class ExperiencesComponent implements OnInit {
  allExperiences: any[] = [];
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _angularFirestore: AngularFirestore,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.allExperiences = (this.route.snapshot.data as any).users;
    this._angularFirestore.collection('experiences', ref => ref.limit(20)).get().pipe(
      map(snapshot => {
        return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          return doc.data();
        });
      }
      ),
      catchError(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
        return of([]);
      })).subscribe(data => {
        this.allExperiences = data;
      })
  }

}
```

experiences.component.html

```
Hello
<div *ngFor="let item of allExperiences">{{ item?.experienceTitle }}</div>
```